# Can I force my video card to work in a certain refresh rate?

Tags: windows, display, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a GeForce GT 640 video card, but by default the screen flickers badly. And if I change the refresh rate to 59 Hz in NVIDIA Control Panel manually, everything is OK. I don't know why.

[image: Change Refresh Rate]

Now the problem is, if the system restarts, the refresh rate become 60Hz, then the screen flicker is flickering. I need to change the refresh rate again.

Can I keep the refresh rate to 59 Hz? Or it would be better if the screen doesn't flicker at 60 Hz.

Comment: Try setting the refresh rate in Windows' Display control panel instead.

Comment: Can't set refresh rate in Windows' Display control panel. It'll become 60 Hz even if I choose 59 Hz.

Comment: Have you tried to set the refresh rate from the `Administrator` account?

Comment: memosdp, that's nonsense. The administrator doesn't have any more privileges in that regard than any other user.

Comment: @memosdp I don't have an Administrator account. And why would I need an Administrator account to set the refresh rate since I can set from the current account? It just can't keep the refresh rate I set.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the customize button and create a custom resolution at 59 hz. Once you've created the custom resolution then apply it like any other resolution.